# Rails undefined method `html_safe' for Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am using Formtastic and on a form I have:

```
<%= f.input :open_date, :as => :string, :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker'}, :start_date => Date.today, label: 'OPEN' %>
```

Then I validate the field with

```
validates :open_date, presence: true
```

If I submit the form with empty field it returns:

```
NoMethodError in Clients#create

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 44ms (ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for Formtastic::Util:Module
Did you mean?  html_safe?):
     6:   <div class="row">
     7: 
     8:     <div class="col-sm-3">
     9:       <%= f.input :open_date, :as => :string, :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker'}, :start_date => Date.today, label: 'OPEN' %>
    10:     </div>
    11: 
    12:     <div class="col-sm-3">
```

I can't find any other way to call datepicker other  than with

```
:input_html => {:class => 'datepicker'}
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Hi @Catmal, Could you show me the complete log?

Comment: Hi, I have posted it but there isn't much more..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I am using formtastic-bootstrap and the issue is already reported [here](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap/issues/141) too.

SO I guess I have no choice but removing the gem.